# How do I merge fonts in Python (fontTools.merge() throws error)

Tags: python, fonts, ttx-fonttools

I tried running this code to merge two fonts but it resulted in an error

Code:

```py
import fontTools as ft
print("Merge v.1.0")


# function to merge
ft.merge("ABeeZee.ttf","NotoEmoji.ttf")
```

Error:
[image]

My file system is fine:

```
  Merge
|
|____    Merge.py
|____    ABeeZee.ttf
|____    NotoEmoji.ttf
```

Comment: Hi can please better explain your aim ?

Comment: Uh, well I simpl need to merge two fonts. One with text and th other one with emojis

Answer (score 1):

use Merger class within the merge module

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from fontTools.merge import Merger
# Open the first font
font2 = "GoogleSans-Medium.ttf"

# Open the second font
font1= "Noto.ttf"

# Merge the fonts
merger = Merger()
new_font = merger.merge([font1, font2])

# Save the merged font
new_font.save("merged_font.ttf")
```